# How do I start counting when below a threshold and stop counting above the same threshold in a timeseries?

Tags: matlab, time-series

I modeled wind speed data for a whole year and now I want to count the amount of consecutive hours that the wind is below a certain threshold. I have to find out the maximum consecutive hours of wind below that threshold. Therefore it should start counting when it hits the threshold and stop counting when the value gets above the threshold again. This will happen multiple times during the year so, like I mentioned, I looking for the max consecutive hours

```
Windspeed_hourly_mean = xlsread('Windspeed_hourly.xlsx','D3:D8762');
WHM=Windspeed_hourly_mean;
threshold = 3;

    isBelow = (WHM < threshold); % gives us a vector of logical values
    isBelow = [false, isBelow, false]; % make sure the vector starts and ends with false
    transitions = diff(isBelow); % gives 1 where false->true and -1 where true->false 
    starts = find(transitions==1); % indexes of where each period starts
    ends = find(transitions==-1); % indexes of where each period ends
    durations = ends - starts;
    max(durations) % largest duration
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a 1 x *n* vector of hourly wind speed values `windSpeed` and your threshold is `threshold` then:

```
isBelow = (windSpeed < threshold); % gives us a vector of logical values
isBelow = [false, isBelow, false]; % make sure the vector starts and ends with false
transitions = diff(isBelow); % gives 1 where false->true and -1 where true->false 
starts = find(transitions==1); % indexes of where each period starts
ends = find(transitions==-1); % indexes of where each period ends
durations = ends - starts;
max(durations) % largest duration
```

Adding `false` to the start and end of the `isBelow` vector is needed so that there is a start  before every end, and so that the `ends` vector is the same length as the `starts` vector.

Comment: Thank you very much. However, I still get an error. I provided the code in my edited question!

Comment: It's no use telling us 'I still get an error' if you don't say what the error is. Have you checked that your `WHM` vector is 1 x *n* in shape, as specified in the answer, or could it be *n* x 1?